# Pyspark says "Row' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' on partitionBy()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Consider the following SchemaRDD:

```
schemaRdd = hiveContext.sql(myQuery)
```

I am unable to use **partitionBy** on it, having tried the following:

```
numParts = 10
schemaRdd.partitionBy(numParts)

schemaRdd.keyBy(lambda row: row[0]).partitionBy(numParts)
```

Both give the "Row' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' error.

How can we then partition the SchemaRdd with 
- selected #partitions
- specific partitioner - I want to also provide second parameter that is a partitioner after the _get_object_id issue is resolved

Comment: My experience with pySpark 1.2.0 - I've used partitionBy(N) for RDDs, but not for any sort of sqlContext object. 

For the former you have to manually change it into a (key,value) format - i.e. if your RDD looks like `(a, b, c)` and you want your key to be a & b, you need to do :  
`rdd = rdd.map(lambda (a,b,c): ((a,b), c)).partitionBy(256)`